# Flask App will not load app.py (The file/path provided (app) does not appear to exist)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

My flask app is outputting 'no content' for the `for()` block and i dont know why.

I tested my query in `app.py` , here is `app.py`:

```
# mysql config
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'user'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'mypass'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'mydbname'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
c = mysql.connect().cursor()
blogposts = c.execute("SELECT post_title, post_name FROM mydbname.wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3")

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def email():
    form = EmailForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return 'Please fill in all fields <p><a href="/">Try Again</a></p>'
        else:
            msg = Message("Message from your visitor",
                          sender='contact@site.com',
                          recipients=['contact@site.com'])
            msg.body = """
            From: %s
            """ % (form.email.data)
            mail.send(msg)
            #return "Successfully  sent message!"
            return render_template('email_submit_thankyou.html')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', blogposts)
```

This is what my `app.py` looks like.

Below is my `index.html` in `templates/`:

```
    <ul>
        {% for blogpost in blogposts %}
        <li><a href="{{blogpost[1]}}">{{blogpost[0]}}</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li>no content...</li>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="clearL"> </div>
    </ul>
```

I checked the query, and it returns desired output like:

```
ID   post_title       post_name
1    a title here     a-title-here
2    a title here2     a-title-here2
3    a title here3     a-title-here3
```

If i try to restart the dev server by running `export FLASK APP=app.py', then`flask run`, i get an error of:

```
Error: The file/path provided (app) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

I've also tried running via `export FLASK_APP=app.py` then `python -m flask run` - this also gives the same error.

Thoughts on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't got anything in your template called `blogposts`. You need to use keyword arguments to pass the data:

```
return render_template('index.html', blogposts=blogposts)
```

Also note you should really do that query inside the function, otherwise it will only ever execute on process start and you'll always have the same three posts.

Comment: Great post, I'm getting an error when i run export `FLASK_APP=app.py`, then `flask run` it gives me an error of `Error: The file/path provided (app) does not appear to exist` thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. You obviously got it to run before, what's changed?

Comment: i know, but after i changed this adding `blogposts=blogposts` its started this. To reiterate when i run `export FLASK_APP=app.py` and then `flask run` to run it on my localhost, it gives me that error

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Daniel - please see updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I solved it as change directory of terminal to the folder containing app.py and then run

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
```

then, you should run

```
python -m flask run
```