# flask.cli.NoAppException: Application crashing

Tags: python, flask

My Flask Application is crashing when I'm trying to access it.

This is similar error to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474520/flask-flask-cli-noappexception-with-app-factory) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403465/flask-app-will-not-load-app-py-the-file-path-provided-app-does-not-appear-to). However, my set-up seems correct.

> flask.cli.NoAppException: The file/path provided (server) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py

My environment variable correctly set.

```
export FLASK_APP=server.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

My server file is `server.py`, and I don't have any `__init__.py` in the directory.

I don't recall having change anything special in the code. Where does the bug could come from?

Comment: Is your server.py in the same directory?

Comment: yes, it is. there is only one directory.

Comment: For anyone having the same issue: if you use virtualenv, check if you activated it :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue was that some package were missing or corrupted.

I reinstalled everything with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed` and now it works fine.

Answer (score 10):

This error may be a sign that an import is not found.
To see which import is missing, try to run your server.py file with the python interpreter:

```
    python yourapp.py
```

Example of output :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "yourapp.py", line 4, in <module>
         from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
    ImportError: No module named flask_httpauth
```

[Source (and other leads)](https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/issues/104)

Comment: ... or, if you have a module, (with `__init__.py` etc.) then do: `python -m yourapp`

Answer (score 0):

For me, solution was fixing a misspelled function name "create_app" in my _ *init* _.py

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

Super late answer, but I just ran into this and the solution was to use a Remote WSL connection in VS Code.  I thought I was in the correct folder, but VS Code was looking at a very similar folder in Windows.  You can tell you're in the wrong folder by running "touch somefile.abc" in your linux terminal, from the project folder, but that file doesn't automatically appear in VS Code's folder structure.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl