# Cannot get flask to run

Tags: python, flask

I have been trying to follow the flask tutorial from [http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/] and i cannot get flask to run.

I get this error

```
File "d:\pyproject\flaskblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 325, in __call__
self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
File "d:\pyproject\flaskblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 313, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
reraise(*exc_info)
File "d:\pyproject\flaskblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "d:\pyproject\flaskblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 302, in _load_app
self._load_unlocked()
File "d:\pyproject\flaskblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 317, in _load_unlocked
self._app = rv = self.loader()
File "d:\pyproject\flaskblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 372, in load_app
app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
File "d:\pyproject\flaskblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 246, in locate_app
'Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name)
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import ""hello.py"".
```

I have tried Reinstalling flask, changing the directory and restarting my computer but to no avail.

I have a hello.py that has the following

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name __)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: Can you post your code snippet ?

Comment: And how do you start it?

Comment: set FLASK_APP="hello.py"->>flask run

Comment: @HughMungus In what folder are you when running the command ?

Comment: D:\Pyproject The app is a subfolder named flaskblog

Comment: You have a space between `name` and the underscore in `__name__`. They need to be together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

put the code in  a folder named test, inside the folder create a new hello.py, paste the following code there

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__) <<<< no space here

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

and cd test, set FLASK_APP=hello.py, flask run, works for me.

Try debugging .... [flask.cli.NoAppException: Application crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979427/flask-cli-noappexception-application-crashing)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure in terminal that cd is set to the current project file
2. Then enter this into terminal (use the file name of your python code in place of app.py)

   - $ export FLASK_APP=app.py
   - $ export FLASK_ENV=development (for debug mode)
   - $ flask run